# What are some good audio resources for learning scientific German?

Tags: pronunciation, learning, reference, audio, scientific-language

[*German Science Reader* by Charles Frederick Kroeh](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/22627) is a book on learning scientific German. However, I learn better aurally. What are some good audio resources for learning scientific German?

Comment: After starting to read the HTML version of the book you linked to I believe it is just a random collection of poorly written paragraphs on various maths, physics or chemistry topics reminiscent of my school books when I was much younger. Sadly there are so many errors that I can hardly recommend it to anybody who needs this for serious scientific publications.

Comment: @Takkat: Thanks for pointing that out. I'm not good enough at German to know whether it's poorly written or not. Are  [Scholz](https://archive.org/details/germansciencere00schogoog)'s or [Gore](https://archive.org/details/germansciencerea00gorerich)'s books, for example, any better? thanks

Comment: @Takkat: could it be that the German is somewhat off because it seems to have been published in 1907? ;)

Comment: A recorded lecture is probably the best you can get. What is the delineation of "scientific", here?

Comment: @Grantwalzer: Physics, specifically; I would like to learn a vocabulary to understand German physics.

Comment: @Gerhard: Does German really evolve that quickly?

Comment: @Geremia I guess a century leaves its traces in any language, and the 20th brought about dramatic change with 2 world wars, changing borders several times in the German speaking area, significant sociological developements - times have changed, and so did the language

Comment: @Geremia what's more, the scientific language has changed a lot - the dominance and influence of the English language was not yet that prominent back then, political correctness has changed quite a bit too, and last but not least the language of science adapted to the changes in scientific progress itself - the accepted definitions of several terms have shifted quite a bit since then.

Comment: @geremia: Hulk already made the most relevant points above. The only thing I have to add is: essentially any "live" language (ie excluding Latin and Ancient Greek) changes over time. Within a century usually not to an extent that it is not understandable, but phrases or pronunciation go in and out of fashion.

Comment: There are a number of recorded lectures available at http://timms.uni-tuebingen.de/Themen/Themen.aspx.

Comment: das Buch kommt mir uralt vor! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you mean by scientific German is the German *Bildungssprache*, a recorded lecture in any subject will be an ideal resource. There is a [website](https://iversity.org/de/courses) which offers MOOCs in German and I am sure you can find more resources of this kind. If you don't care about the content and just want a lot of very beautiful, sophisticated and precise German, I recommend podcasts in the legal disciplines (for example from LMU Munich). In my view, German legal vocabulary is where beauty and precision are most concentrated, and the discipline is less prone to loanwords so that what you learn is originally German most of the time, which is not the case in the vast majority of other sciences.

If, however, you mean **scientific** terminology in a strict sense, a very substantial part of that is based on Latin and Greek and thus quite similar across languages ("Homoscedasticity", "Homoscédasticité", "Homocedasticidad", "Homoskedastizität" etc.) and it would be best to look for a book on the etymology of scientific terminology.